FirebaseError: Invalid document reference. Document references must have an even number of segments, but table/table1/recipe0 has 3
I have a college project that uses react native to create a app, we have to use firebase to make the database and use it inside of hte pages, i have a problem where i have a page that you can look at the products, this page has a button that when pressed it changes the product in the page and shows the next one, i have 5 buttons at the top of the page to assign to different tables, i basically have to access a specific field of the subcollection of the collection but it returns the error in the title everytime i press the button:
Firebase:

code:
  const [trocar, setTrocar] = useState(0);
    const [selectedTable, setSelectedTable] = useState(1);
    const [ldata, setLData] = useState({});


const incrementRecipeTab = async (trocar, selectedTable) => {
        try {
            // Determine the subcollection path based on the selected table
            const subcollectionName = `table${selectedTable}`;
            
            // Document reference for the specific recipe
            const recipeDocPath = `table/${subcollectionName}/recipe${trocar}`;
            const recipeDocRef = doc(db, recipeDocPath);
            
            // Log the path to debug
            console.log(`Document path: ${recipeDocPath}`);
            
            // Get the document snapshot
            const recipeDocSnapshot = await getDoc(recipeDocRef);
            
            if (recipeDocSnapshot.exists()) {
                // Increment the specific recipe field
                await updateDoc(recipeDocRef, {
                    [`recipe${trocar}`]: increment(1) // Increment dynamically
                });
    
                console.log(`Recipe ${trocar} incremented successfully for table ${selectedTable}`);
            } else {
                console.error(`Recipe document does not exist for table ${selectedTable} at path ${recipeDocPath}`);
            }
        } catch (ex) {
            console.error('Error incrementing recipe:', ex);
        }
    };

    const handleAddPress = () => {
        // Adicionar logs para debug
        console.log('Current Recipe:', trocar);
        console.log('Table ID:', selectedTable);
    
        // Validar os valores antes de chamar a função
        if (trocar != null && selectedTable != null) {
            incrementRecipeTab(trocar, selectedTable);
        } else {
            console.error('trocar or selectedTable is not defined');
        }
    };

    
    const renderItem = (item) => (
        <View>
            {item && (
                <View style={[styles.container, { marginTop: 8 + rowGap }]}>
                    <View style={styles.column}>
                        <Image source={item.image} style={styles.imagPrato} />
                        <View style={styles.textBoxContainer}>
                            <Text style={styles.boxText}>{item.name}</Text>
                            <Text style={styles.boxTextTemp}>{item.time} Minutes</Text>
                            <View style={styles.imageVectorContainer}>
                                <Image source={require("../assets/Vector.png")} style={styles.imageVector} />
                            </View>
                            <View style={styles.rectangle}>
                                <Text style={[styles.boxText, { color: 'white', top: '31%', position: 'relative' }]}>Recipe:</Text>
                            </View>
                            <View style={[styles.rectangle, { left: '55%' }]}>
                                <Text style={[styles.boxText, { color: 'white', top: '31%', position: 'relative' }]}>Price: {item.price} €</Text>
                            </View>
                            <View style={styles.textboxContainerIngre}>
                                <Text>{item.recipe}</Text>
                            </View>
                            <View style={styles.rectangleCenter}>
                                <Text style={[styles.boxText, { color: 'white', top: '31%', position: 'relative' }]}>Preparation:</Text>
                            </View>
                            <View style={[styles.textboxContainerIngre, { top: '160%' }]}>
                                <Text>{item.preparation}</Text>
                            </View>
                            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => handleAddPress()} style={styles.rectangleadd}>
                                <Text style={[styles.boxText, { color: 'white', top: '31%', position: 'relative' }]}>Add: {item.quant}</Text>
                            </TouchableOpacity>
                        </View>
                        <Button onPress={HandlePress} title="Next" />
                    </View>
                </View>
            )}
        </View>
);    `

If someone want more parts of the code, just ask
I want to increment the recipe[trocar], trocar being the current product in the assigned selecttable that shows in the page, i can't seem to get why it's showing that error

I think you misunderstand Firestore terminology.  Here is how you would describe each of the components you see in your screenshot:

"table" is a collection
"table2" is a document ID (not a subcollection)
"recipe0" - "recipe4" are fields in document table2

It appears you are trying to read a field of a document individually.  That's not possible.  Instead, you can read the entire document, then access each field of that document in the resulting document snapshot.
const docRef = doc(db, "table/table2");
const snapshot = await getDoc(docRef);
const data = snapshot.data();  // this is an object whose entries are document fields
console.log(snapshot.data()); // this will print all of the fields in the doc

You can then update a field in a document using its correct reference:
await updateDoc(docRef, {
    [`recipe${trocar}`]: increment(1)
});

